# Reading and display the csv file that is read in C#

Tags: c#

I just started learning C#, so sorry if this if this is an elementary problem.

I wrote a little code to display read in the csv files, but I am not sure how to display what is being read in. Below is the code I have written:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\syang\Desktop\file.csv"));
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            listA.Add(values[0]);
            listB.Add(values[1]);
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want to just display to console? `Console.WriteLine(line);`

Comment: There are tools to do that for you - splitting on "," has many problems

Comment: Use *File.ReadAllLines* instead of StreamReader, otherwise stream should be closed (explicitly or by *using(){}* ).

Answer (score 2):

Create a method for displaying

```
static void Display(string input)
{
    Console.Write(input + " ");
}
```

Then in your Main method just call it for every member at the end...

```
...
    listA.Add(values[0]);
    listB.Add(values[1]);
}
listA.ForEach(Display);
```

If you want a different format for displaying items, you can change the `Console.Write` part.

If you want them on a single line or something else that's just as simple, you can do it in one line:

```
listA.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

However, in this version of your code, you're making 2 assumptions:

1. No item contains a comma
2. The file is indeed separated with commas (and not some other symbol)
3. Every line contains at least two items

There's no definitive spec for the CSV format, so unless you're creating the CSV yourself (or you get it from a trusted entity), you can't trust anyone with those three above.